# Move cursor to beginning of MaskedTextBox on focus

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, maskedtextbox

When a user is tabbing through a form and focus gets set on a Kendo-Ui for Angular2 MaskedTextBox, the input cursor is at the end of the mask.  This is very inconvenient for a user when doing data entry.

I have tried to use the onfocus event to reset the cursor, but the event does not seem to fire for this object.

```
                <kendo-maskedtextbox
                    onfocus="console.log('focused'); this.setSelectionRange(0,0);"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="phone"
                    [(ngModel)]="phone.phoneNumber" 
                    [mask]="phoneMask"
                    required>
                </kendo-maskedtextbox>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated....

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Any fix for this issue? @adova I also have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The most recent versions of the controls fixed my problems.